# Deleting a directory as a non-owner of the directory

Tags: linux, unix

I have a directory with full permissions with root as owner. What I want is to be able to remove it as a normal user. However, i am not allowed to do so:

```
radu@Workstation:/tmp$ ls -l | grep cucu
drwxrwxrwx 2 root   root    4096 oct 20 10:28 cucu

radu@Workstation:/tmp$ ls -la cucu
total 52
drwxrwxrwx  2 root root  4096 oct 20 10:28 .
drwxrwxrwt 66 root root 45056 oct 20 10:28 ..

radu@Workstation:/tmp$ rm -r cucu
rm: cannot remove 'cucu': Operation not permitted
```

What do I not get right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing a directory (or a file) consists in deleting its entry into its containing directory, so to remove `cucu` you need permissions on its parent; alas access rights are `rwxrwxrwt`, and the `t` means *removal authorized for owner only*, as the owner is `root`, only root can remove `cucu`.

Answer (score 1):

Sticky bit is set , so only owner can remove the directory.

Answer (score 0):

This is because only root has the permission to remove directory, as you can see

drwxrwxrwx 2 **root   root**    4096 oct 20 10:28 cucu

From your root, change the Permission of directory using **chown**. For example-

chown radu cucu

Check this out for more info on chown command on linux. 
http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/06/chown-examples